# Why doesn't libevent include built-in https support?

Tags: https, libevent

I'm trying to find a good library to deal with large number of concurrent connections and I came across [Libevent](http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) and [Libev](http://libev.schmorp.de/). But neither of them has built-in ssl/https support. I'm wondering if I'm missing something here on how these libraries should be used because ssl/https is so commonly used yet it's not in these two popular tools.

Answer (score 1):

I believe libevent2 has support for SSL.

http://levent.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=levent/levent;a=blob;f=ChangeLog;hb=fe008ed656766266b93cdf2083f5b8bc50e6aad3

Comment: Libevent 2.0 has ssl, but not https. There's an https patch panding for 2.1.